# Allow strong-name signing

Tags: appveyor

I added the ability to handle delay signing to a project on GitHub:
https://github.com/ryknuth/Fody

I added a test for this and everything builds fine locally. However, when I submit my PullRequest, it runs through AppVeyor which fails:

MSBUILD : error : Fody: An unhandled exception occurred: [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error : Exception: [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error : Strong-name signing is not supported on this platform. [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error : Type: [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error : System.PlatformNotSupportedException [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error : StackTrace: [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error :    at System.Reflection.StrongNameKeyPair.get_PublicKey() [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error :    at InnerWeaver.FindStrongNameKey() in C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\StrongNameKeyFinder.cs:line 27 [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error :    at InnerWeaver.Execute() in C:\projects\fody\FodyIsolated\InnerWeaver.cs:line 112 [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error : Source: [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error : System.Private.CoreLib [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error : TargetSite: [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error : Byte[] get_PublicKey() [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]
MSBUILD : error :  [C:\projects\fody\Integration\WithDelaySigning\WithDelaySigning.csproj]

Is there a way to enable signing or perhaps disable building this project in AppVeyor?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution which seems to work is replacing

```
dotnet build Integration\Integration.sln --configuration Release
```

with

```
msbuild Integration\Integration.sln /target:Restore
msbuild Integration\Integration.sln /p:Configuration=Release /verbosity:minimal
```

Not sure I deeply understand the underlying issue, but this should unblock you.

Side note: to disable building a project you can remove it from the configuration which you are building e.g. `Release` in your case, in VS and saving the solution.